# Azure CosmosDB Table API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have my IoT data flow as below:
Azure IoT Hub(JSON Data)->Stream Analytics->Azure CosmosDB Table API(Table name= Test)

The input to the Streaming Analytics is  from IoT Hub(sensor data in JSON format). And I have two outputs from the Streaming Analytics, one is Azure CosmosDB(Table API, Table name is 'Test1' and another output is configured to Blob Storage. The streaming analytics query used for both outputs is same.

Q. I am able to see the data in azure ablob storage container, but I am not able to see the data in 'Test1' table of Azure CosmosDB(Table API) through portal. Please find attached screen shots for reference.

Thanks,

Siva M

[Azure CosmosDB TableAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfN4U.png)
[ASA Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Frq.png)

Comment: Can you explain how are you writing to Tables API? Is it through Azure Functions?

Answer (score 0):

Right now Azure Streaming analytics does not support outputting to Azure Cosmos DB Table API.
   Thanks,
              Yaron

Comment: is this still the case?